# "myDropzone.emit is not a function" Dropzone js

Tags: dropzone.js

I succesfully parsed some photos from the server to repopulate a form Post. Now I need them to be displayed
I have this code and with a firefox console the data is stored correctly in mockFile but when the time of pulling I got the myDrzone.emit is not a function.
here is the code. (Im new to javascript)

```
init: function () {

$.get('/getphoto',{'key': $('[name=key]').val()},function(data){
        var files = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            var mockFile = {
                url: files[i].url,
                size: files[i].size,
                name: files[i].name

            };
            var myDropzone = this;
            myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile); //here I get the error
            myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile);
            myDropzone.emit("success", mockFile); 

            var existingFileCount = 1; // The number of files already uploaded
            myDropzone.options.maxFiles = myDropzone.options.maxFiles - existingFileCount;
        }

        });
```

I have the Jquery plugin set before the dropzone.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to move

```
var myDropzone = this;
```

just after

```
init: function () {
```

to fix the problem.
As Im new to Javascript I dont really know the process of declaring the variables.